# How can I pass sp parameter with N prefix

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

I want to pass a parameter to sp with N prefix to solve an issue with foreign languages characters recognized as ???, I can't put N@test, directly, tried different ways without luck.

I have aspx.cs code file where I call to an sp, I want to do something like the following:

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR = 'N"★ "' 
create table test (abc nvarchar) 
insert into test values (@test) 
select * from test
```

the code above is just an example, I will pass value to the parameter from .NET, How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need N prefix. You can specify parameter type as `SqlDbType.NVarChar` along with size. .Net will take care of preserving text encoding.

```
var foo = new SqlParameter("@test ", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

`N` prefix means that your string is in UNICODE.

When you declare your variable as `NVARCHAR` it is already UNICODE.

So you don't need this `N` lineral at the begin of your variable.